# html entity encode text only, not html tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a string that contains a bunch of html. i want to html-encode the text within the html tags but not the tags themselves. is there an easy way to do this in asp.net c# 3.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net) (available via nuget) to read the HTML then if necessary use the HtmlEncode method to encode the specific values by querying them.

Comment: although i am already using it, i have always had trouble opening documentation file(.chm) of agility pack

Comment: [Problem with help document](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/69349?ProjectName=htmlagilitypack)

Comment: thanks myName didnt even know it was a windows problem. always thought something was wrong with the chm file.

Comment: and the answer is as simple as content = HtmlEntity.Entitize(content);

Answer (score 0):

if you need a bunch of functions use the htmlagilitypack. if you just need urls or something in specific tags a selfwritten parser would be more efficient