# How to encode special characters in HTML but exclude tags

Tags: c#, html, character-encoding

I'm trying to convert an HTML page into one containing proper named entities, converting quotes, double quotes to entities. I tried the following code which works but encodes the HTML tags, which I want to leave alone. Any ideas how to do this?

```
public static string HtmlEncode(string text)
{
    string result;
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var x = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        x.WriteEncodedText(text);
        result = sw.ToString();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You're right Matt, the answer was in that previous question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by MatthewG above, the answer had already been posted to [html entity encode text only, not html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464686/html-entity-encode-text-only-not-html-tag) - the solution is to use HTMLAgilityPack and pass the html text or node to the method entitize - this encodes only the page content and not the tags.

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
html = HtmlEntity.Entitize(html);
```