# How to encode special characters in HTML (encode, not entitize) but exclude HTML tags

Tags: c#, html, html-encode

So I'm trying to encode html special characters (like ®, &, ©) I find on the front-end, but I can't figure out how to avoid also encoding HTML tags `(like <br>, or <i>)`.

This is what I've tried so far:

`var encodedHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Encode this: ®, &, © but not this: <b>")`

`Console.WriteLine(encodedHtml);`

The result is: `Encode this: &#174;, &amp;, &#169; but not this: &lt;b&gt;`

The result I want is this: `Encode this: &#174;, &amp;, &#169; but not this: <b>`

I've also tried this, based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301206/how-to-encode-special-characters-in-html-but-exclude-tags):

`var entitizedHtml = HtmlEntity.Entitize("Encode this:®, &, © but not this: <b>");`
`Console.WriteLine(entitizedHtml );`

The result is:`Encode this: &reg;, &, &reg; but not this: <b>`

The entitized result is close to what I want, but I'm trying to see if I can convert the the HTML special characters to their HTML code versions rather than their HTML entity versions.

Anyone have any suggestions? I'm thinking I might have to figure out how to parse through the string to check for HTML tags, but I'm not too sure what the best way to do that is.

Comment: `var encodedHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Encode this: ®, &, © but not this: ") + "<b>";`

Comment: @PoulBak This was just an example, like I'll run into html tags scattered throughout the string among special characters, so I don't think I can just append the tags to the end.